# What is this plant ...?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I would like to know what is this plant ? Does anybody have an idea ? Somebody offered it to me but there is no explanation about how to care about it... 
Some purple flowers appeared, during 2-3 days. And now it seems it lacks something, but I don't really know what to do :(

[image: unknown plant]

Any idea ?
Thank you very much !

Comment: What other information can you add about the plant? But also see [this](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/151/plant-identification-questions) meta post.

Comment: As we can see on the picture, there are green small and thin leaves, and a big pink part in the middle. When I give water to the plant, this pink part seems to "drink" and fill up with water, as when we touch it, it is wet, like a sponge...
A few days after I got the plant, purple flowers appeared (as on the picture), and wilted 2-3 days after.
Now, the pink part is fading, and turning grey/green...
I have no idea about where this plant is from. But it seems that it is an indoor plant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a beautiful Pink Quill, or Tillandsia cyanea. I have included two websites below about this plant, both of which include care tips.

1. http://home-and-gardening.info/2009/09/18/a-guide-on-growing-tillandsia/
2. http://houseplants.about.com/od/bromeliads/a/Bromeliads.htm

Comment: My pleasure! Enjoy!